# How do you use authenticate_with_http_token with rails-api?

Tags: rails-api

I am using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) and need to use `authenticate_with_http_token` to process a header authorization token, but i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_with_http_token' for ...)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add the following to `ApplicationController`

```rb
include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
```